# Detect Close event of Side nav on MaterializeCSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Is there a way to detect the event that will close the side-nav ?

I tried to use the overlay that was being displayed when side nav is open

```
  $('#sidenav-overlay').click(function(){
       toggleSidebar();
  });
```

However it did not work.
I am not sure what to use based on the [documentation](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html), but what I am trying to do was when event that will close the side detected I will call a specific function
like in my case is function toggleSidebar()

Here is the sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2nzovd6/

Comment: Callback functions in `options` aren't working?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option `onCloseEnd` in Materialize v1 which you should be using. Your fiddle uses a very old 0.95 version

Here is how you would use it
http://jsfiddle.net/hv0poe46/

Comment: Appreciate your response. Would you be able to create a fiddle for this fix as I am a bit confuse on how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: I tried to update the version and add onCloseEnd however I encountered error 
See: http://jsfiddle.net/u2nzovd6/39/